# How is regsubsets in R's leaps package optimized under the hood for exhaustive model selection searches?

Tags: r, brute-force

I'm running some model selection procedures based on 43 surveys of people who gave answers to about 50 variables.  I have narrowed the useful enough variables down to 22 and discarded the rest.

I wanted to perform a model selection using the exhaustive regsubsets algo from the leaps library in R.  I set nvmax=22 - the number of predictors in my set - regsubsets blew me away with its speed - just a few seconds to run 2^22 ~ 4 million regressions.  This cannot possibly be enumerating all of the combinations of 22 choose k for all k from 1 to 22 and regressing, can it?

Is regsubsets optimized in some way so that the "exhaustive" algo can cleverly omit the vast majority of regressions that it can know a priori will have a bad R^2 relative to the best available?

I found that when I ran lm(y~.x, data=some.df), this took 25 seconds for only 10,000 regressions - a far cry from the 3 or 4 seconds it took regsubsets to analyze 4 million regressions - so it clearly has some optimization in the code.  How is that optimization implemented?

Comment: Got a sufficient answer straight from the horse's mouth below - Thomas Lumley is responsible for maintaining the code for the leaps package in R.  Further details can be derived by looking into the papers regarding the branch and bound algo.

Comment: This is a very important question. Why this question is closed. Anyway, very useful reference to understand the algorithm behind the leaps is here: http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/aim/2009/work/thesis.pdf

Comment: @Chandra - thx.  I thought it reasonable- which is especially true given that two short paragraphs below made for an actual answer.  Maybe a little too mathy for software people I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The underlying Fortran code (by Allan Miller) uses a branch-and-bound algorithm based on the original ideas by Furnival & Wilson (Technometrics, 1974). This rules out large chunks of model space based on the principal that removing variables from a model can only increase the residual sum of squares.

The implementation is also efficient, computing only the residual sum of squares for each model, and computing the QR decomposition of the predictors only once.

Comment: Alan Miller's Fortran source code can be found here http://jblevins.org/mirror/amiller/
Together with the original Furnival & Wilson's paper
http://www.stat.washington.edu/adobra/classes/536/Files/week3/leapsandbounds.pdf
This is really an ingenious algorithm.